# Cannot GET from endpoint in Express.js

Tags: node.js, express, url, postman

I have two endpoints in my express app, one is /ping - doesnt take any parameters and is working fine, the other is /posts which takes one mandatory parameter 'tag' and two optional ones 'sortBy' and 'direction'.

The app starts, and in Postman the /ping works fine on GET, however the /posts is not working as expected

```
const express = require('express')
const apicache = require('apicache')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080; //use 8080 or use whatever Heroku gives you
const { ping, getPosts } = require('./controller')

const app = express()
//app.use(express.json())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
const cache = apicache.middleware; //as described on https://www.npmjs.com/package/apicache

app.get('/api/ping', ping) //the first requirement, a ping endpoint


app.get('/api/posts/:tag/:sortBy?/:direction?', cache('5 minutes'), getPosts) //second requirement, an endpoint that fetches posts from the hatchways website

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

Now as per Express's docs I would expect the url "localhost:8080/api/posts?tag=tech" to work, however Postman says cannot GET /api/posts
What does work is hitting the url "localhost:8080/api/posts/tag/tech" which is not what this app is expected to respond to.

I think I am missing something about URL specifications. I do need it to work on "localhost:8080/api/posts?tag=tech"
and not
"localhost:8080/api/posts/tag/tech"

Help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are a bit confused about queries and route parameters.

A query is a part of the URL, and it looks like this:

```
https://example.com/api/posts?tag=tech&this=that+something
```

While route parameters are (kind of) similar, they are not the same. It looks like a regular URL, but parts of it could be different.

Currently, you are defining your express route to accept [route parameters](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#route-parameters), and not [queries](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query). To make it work on queries, just do this:

```js
// Remove the 3 route parameters, and do this instead.
app.get('/api/posts', cache('5 minutes'), getPosts);
```

And, make sure you use `req.query` in your `getPosts` controller:

```js
exports.getPosts = function(req, res) {
  // Get whatever you need in req.query
  // In your case you need tag, sortBy, and direction.
  const { tag, sortBy, direction } = req.query;

  // You API code.
}
```

Now, your express API should function as expected.

Comment: yep ended up doing just that after seeing no answer for 15 minutes! Cheers

Comment: @ashishparalkar you might want to mark this as the answer so it is marked as solved